# Window ▶ Show Handwriting Input

Tags: version-10, windows

How might I force Mathematica to display the Handwriting Input menu?

Currently I'm on W7 using a Wacom Tablet and unable to find the [Handwriting Input](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/HandwrittenMathRecognition.html) option.

It doesn't display under Windows>.

Comment: Have you turned on the ["Tablet PC Components"](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-7/turn-on-windows-tablet-pc-components-in-windows-7/) in Windows 7?

Comment: @chuy Yes.  Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain why and when this does or doesn't work, but do a windows search for `Math Input Panel`  allows me to enter equations using the Windows input panel.